# Reorganization of excel table data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that is formatted like the one in the attached image (Current table).

The question I have is that the same column contains data of different level (in this case, Continent-Nation-City). Normally I manually add columns and using the filters and simple formula to copy the content of the cell I can get the table in the second image (Desired table).

While this works for small amounts of data, when it comes to table with thousands of rows it may become quite time consuming.

Is there another, more efficient, way to reorganize the table from the "Current table" to the "Desired table?"

Current table:

[image: Current table.]

Desired table:

[image: Desired table.]

Comment: Trying to build the logic in a lookup table in excel may not be ideal, unless the number of unique locations is reatively few (less then 50, but I've done much more). I think it would be more efficient to get the Continent/Nation/City "hierarchy" from the source, that way no transformation is needed.

Comment: This looks to be a relatively simple task for Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365). If you cannot figure out a solution, I suggest you edit your question to post your sample data as text, which can be easily copy/pasted into a workbook. Is there a fixed number of cities per country? Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Do all of your tables have just a single Continent? Do all of your Countries have the same number of Cities?  If not and you are using PQ, you will need a List of Continents, and a List of countries to be able to differentiate.  OTOH, if the cell interior color is always as you show, you can create a VBA macro to select Continents and Cities by color.

Comment: How can i paste the table in my post? Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: Try this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). After you paste it, select the entire table and then the "Code" icon or hit `ctrl+K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my favorite trick in Excel and here is the way to do it.

It seems like there are many steps, but they are very simple and it takes usually some 10-20 secs to do it all when you know it. And you definitely should learn it for future as it is needed very often.

1. filter "location" column by color orange only
2. select all the cells in new column for Continent (to make it quicker select the last cell in the new column and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>)
3. Home -> Find&Select -> Go to special -> Visible cells only -> OK
4. Now, keeping the active selection, start inputting simple formula:

   ```
   =[@[Location]]
   ```

   or just:

   ```
   =B2
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so the formula is copied to all the previously selected cells. Now, since it is a tabled range you are using as I see, be careful so that the formula is not auto-populated to other cells. If so, just press CRTL+Z once.
6. Exit filter.
7. Now select all the cells in the new "continent" column
8. Home -> Find&Select -> Go to special -> Blanks -> OK
9. Press <kbd>=</kbd> and then <kbd>Up</kbd> and then <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. What this does is it will reference all the items with empty cells in new "Continent" column to their mother hierarchy continent.

Now you can repeat the same actions for the second level hierarchy in the new column "Nation" this time filtering green color. And repeat it as much hierarchy levels you have.

In the end you have to copy all the data in new columns and past as values so that there are no formulas that you do not need anymore.

And finally, only now you can again filter with color orange and green rows and delete them. Afterwords rename you column "Location" to "City". And you should have what is called "Flat table" and is best for further analytical work with the data with PivotTalbes etc.

Comment: Thanks. It works very well and the tricks you just teached me can be very helpful